# SQL Assistance Do I run a Query on a dabase using BETWEEN a date from 5PM to 7AM the next day?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return a ticket count from 5PM on one day to 7am the following day. 
I tried using the following query using DATEADD but it isn't returning any results:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.TicketIncidents
WHERE IncidentReportedDt BETWEEN 
DATEADD(hh,17,CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), GETDATE(),110))
and DATEADD(hh,7,CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), GETDATE()+1,110))
```

does anyone have any suggestions to making this work? Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to  check the format of the IncidentReportedDt column to match with the format that you compare with

Comment: IncidentReportedDt is a varchar or a datetime?

Comment: run on my server gives "La conversione di un tipo di dati varchar in datetime ha generato un valore non compreso nell'intervallo dei valori consentiti.", it is a conversion error because of the platform-dependant implicit conversion from varchar to datetime

Comment: have you solved? have you found any answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

Try using CAST and adding 31 hours:

```
Declare @date as datetime = '2017-09-29 12:00:00.000'

SELECT * FROM dbo.TicketIncidents
WHERE IncidentReportedDt BETWEEN 
DATEADD(hour,17,cast(Cast(@date as date) as datetime))
and DATEADD(hour,31,cast(Cast(@date as date) as datetime))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use

```
DATEADD(hh, 17, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
```

instead of

```
DATEADD(hh,17,CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), GETDATE(),110))
```

because converting to varchar in a platform-dependant format a date to convert it again to a datetime is a non the best way to do it

**In my italian server your syntax throw a conversion error from varchar to datetime**

Comment: While it's not the *best* way to truncate the `TIME` portion of a `DATETIME`, it most certainly isn't nonsense.  Your answer would only add 17 hours to the current time, drop the time, keeping only the date, whilst also converting it to a `VARCHAR`.  That isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: You are wrong, converting GETDATE() to VARCHAR is nonsense because if he wants to truncate TIME part he should use CONVERT to DATE, and also he after use it in DATEADD that require a DATE/DATETIME, so sql-server convert again it to DATE

Comment: it returns a varchar.. now you run SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

Comment: You're missing the point, completely.... both statements will return the same thing.  One as a `varchar`, the other as a `date`.  It's two different ways of getting the *exact same result*.  Converting to a `varchar` is no different in this context as converting to a `date`.  Calling one nonsensical and dismissing it is just pedantic.  I wouldn't do it this way, I'd convert it to a `date`, but I wouldn't say the other way is invalid.

Comment: if you convert to varchar (110) you force the implicit conversion to date(time) and if you will run it on a different (non USA) server you can get wrong results